# Handle cookie in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an Spring MVC application which using the classic three layer: controller service and dao.

And the related models in the application contains `User` `Department` `Project`.

One user will belong to a department, and there may be a lot of projects belong to a certain department, and the departments are organized as a tree like structure, for example:

```
dep1
    dep1-1
        dep1-1-1
        dep1-1-2
        ...
    ...
...
```

Now I have a controller to list the projects:

```
class ProjectController{
    private ProjectService projectService;
    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String list(@RequestParameter("depId") String depId){
        projectService.list(depId);
        return "list";
    }
}

ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService{
    ProjectDao projectDao;
    public List<Department> list(String depId){

    }
}
```

It seems that this is rather simple, however we have two problems:

1 The result filter.

According to the configuration, the department of the current user maybe(or not) be under consideration during the query operation, for example, when the parameter `depId` is `dep1-1-1`, and the current user belongs to `dep1-1-2`, then we should return null.

As said, this feature maybe closed at all at some situation.

2 The authentication.

The user authentication and management is served in another application which will deployed at the same domain with my application, you can think they are two different folder inside the `/tomcat/webapps`. We use cookie to share the user information:save a token for a user.

Which means for every request, I will have to get the token of the current user(if they have login) from the cookie, and then call the service provided by the other application to get the information like `department` and etc.

So where to do the department check, in controller or service? I am not sure if inject the `HttpRequest` to service is a good idea or not.

Also Since there are too many controllers and services related to this kind of operation, I want to avoid the duplicate codes everywhere.

Is there any better choices?

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill, but what you are asking for make me think to spring-security :

- authentication : spring security could do it directly, but you can also implement a custom `PreauthenticatedAuthenticationFilter` that would use the cookie to get the user info and populates a Spring Security `Authentication` token. This part is easy and highly configurable.
- result filter : extract from the spring security reference manual :

  *Spring Security supports filtering of collections and arrays and this can now be achieved using expressions. This is most commonly performed on the return value of a method. For example:*

  ```
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
  @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read') or hasPermission(filterObject, 'admin')")
  public List<Contact> getAll();
  ```

  *When using the @PostFilter annotation, Spring Security iterates through the returned collection and removes any elements for which the supplied expression is false*

  All this is implemented through Spring AOP so it is easy to add those annotations on service methods.

Spring Security integrates nicely in a Spring MVC application. The only problem is that a full configuration including domain object security is not really trivial ...

Comment: Good idea, but the other application which serve the user management does not use ss at the moment, and there is a little change to change the current project structure.

Comment: And for the `postfilter` which will filter the result after the querying from the database, this is un-acceptable in our application, since the query may be complex, so we prefer to use the filter condition in the database level.